# Medication reminder app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a medication reminder app and here is how it works; it creates a directory to store new medications' details as the user enters them, these are stored as a text file with the name of the medication as the file identifier. The user would then be able to view a list of stored medications and their details with the help of a method that searches the directory. However, upon deleting one medication file from the directory, its name remains in the listBox that shows existing names, I can still create a new file with the same name and the names will be displayed together. I think i am failing to clear the contents of the ListBox that shows the list of existing files but i have tried my best i still cannot get it working. The code i use for deleteing the file is as follows:

```
    try
    {
       // string fileName = medListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";
        IsolatedStorageFile storageAccessor = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        /*while (storageAccessor.FileExists(fileName))
            storageAccessor.DeleteFile(fileName);*/
        storageAccessor.CreateDirectory("MedicationDetails");
        // string fileHolderReAppear = medListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";
        storageAccessor.DeleteFile(medListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted successfully!");


        using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MedDetailsFile.txt", FileMode.Open, storageAccessor))
        {
            string buff;
            using (var isoFileReader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
            {
                while ((buff = isoFileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                       medListBox.Items.Remove(buff);

                }

            }
        }
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/medicationList.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
    catch (Exception exception3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!!", exception3.Message, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: How are you populating your ListBox?  Nothing in the Code you showed deletes the SelectedItem from the ListBox.  How are you expecting the ListBox to remove the SelectedItem corresponding to the File you deleted?

Comment: Mike if you look at the bit of code just before the message "Deleted successfully " i used that code to delete the selected item